# Evaluate a function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a function f, g, and h, all with the source and target of {1, 2, 3, 4} which are defined as:

- f = {(1,1),(2,3),(4,2)}
- g = {(1,4),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3)}
- h = {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)}

now, I've been asked to evaluate the following:

1. f(4)
2. g(2)
3. h(g(4))
4. g(h(f(1)))
5. g(g(3))
6. double(f(3))

I believe I understand how to do the simpler functions, such as nr 1, 2, and 6 but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the nested functions.

Comment: What is a "source target"?

Comment: It is useful to identify a function with its graph and that is what has been done here in this exercise. You have if you see careful:
    $$\begin{cases}f(4)=2\\g(2)=1\\h(g(4))=h(3)=3\\g(h(f(1)))=g(h(1))=g(1)=4\\g(g(3))=g(2)=1\end{cases}$$ I don't know what does mean double$f(3)$ and note that $f(3)$ is not defined.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It should've said "source and target".

Comment: Another helpful way to visualize this is to make a function diagram similar to the graphic under the heading "Definition." For example, in the domain bubble for f you would write {1,2,4} and in the one for range you'd write {1,3,2}. Next you'd draw arrows mapping the domain values to the range values.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to be upfront and say that I'm not entirely sure I understand your question correctly but here are my thoughts:

your post reminds me of cycle permutation notation. (If you're unfamiliar with the concept here's a link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation)

f = {(1,1),(2,3),(4,2)}
g = {(1,4),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3)}
h = {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)}

We see in the case of f 1 maps to 1, 2 maps to 3, and 4 maps to 2.

In this case I'd look at something like g(3) and notice 3 maps to 2. Although we don't have an explicit relation through the problem proposed we can still see what's happening.

In the case of a composition, I can look at something like h(f(2)) and notice 2 maps to 3 in f. Now I look for h(3), which carries 3 to itself, so h(f(2))=3.

Comment: This is not the same as the notation used for cyclic permutations. For instance $(1,2)$ in this notation will map $1$ to $2$ *and* map $2$ to $1$, not just the former. The rest of your answer seems correct, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) . I could see where the confusion would arise. I mentioned cycle notation because I wanted something concrete to base my explanation off of, an anchor point if you will. I did not intend to convey or suggest that these were the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

In $f$ you have $(4,2)$ so $f(4)=2$.
In $g$ you have $(2,1)$ so $g(2)=1$. Now $g(4)=3$ then in $h$ we have $(3,3)$ then $h(g(4))=3$. Now $f(1)=1$ then $h(f(1))=1$, then $g(h(f(1)))=4$. Finally $g(3)=2$ then $g(g(3))=1$

Answer (score 0):

You must be aware of **composite functions**
Let me tell some of the basics
If there is a function like *fog* it basically means *f(g(x))*
You input x will produce an output g(x) which is used as input for f( ), producing an output, which is nothing but f(g(x))
With this knowledge I would ask you to try the questions again